# Does C use short circuit evaluation even when arguments are function calls?

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators

I know that logical operators do short-circuit checking.  That is, if there is a statement like `A && B && C`, then if `A` is false, `B` and `C` are not evaluated.  But is this also true in cases where `B` and `C` are function calls?

For example, the return statement in this code:

```
bool areIdentical(struct node * root1, struct node *root2)
{
    /* base cases */
    if(root1 == NULL && root2 == NULL)
        return true;

    if(root1 == NULL || root2 == NULL)
        return false;

    /* Check if the data of both roots is same and data of left and right
       subtrees are also same */
    return (root1->data == root2->data   &&               //I am talking about this statement
            areIdentical(root1->left, root2->left) &&
            areIdentical(root1->right, root2->right) );  
}
```

Comment: same logic should apply. Have you tested it? what does the output tell you ?

Comment: Since program is not changing anything so there is no way of knowing if it calls the function for left subtree and right subtree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the functions are not called if `root1->data == root2->data` is `false`.

Simple check is to do this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  write(1, "z", 1);
  if ((1 == 0) && write(1, "a", 1) && write(1, "b", 1))
  {
    write(1, "c", 1);
  }
  write(1, "d", 1);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You can also show that the assembly dump would have placed the function call after the conditional branches

Comment: That is right, thanks. If you would like to add this to my answer you can go ahead and edit it :)

Comment: Nah, I was just preparing a similar example and got beaten fair and square. To the winner goes the rep :)

Comment: Well I don't take this as a contest and merely answers the best I can to provide people with the information they seek :)

Comment: I am going to assume you have a typo but it is hard to know since you don't actually explain the expected output of the program. `logical and` will short circuit if the first operand is `false` not `true` as you currently state. Your statement would be true for `logical or`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Oh yes, that was indeed a typo. I was cloud-minded when I first posted the answer and gave it some edits, I missed that! That's corrected, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The *Logical and operator* will short circuit regardless of what the *operands* are, if we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.13` *Logical AND operator* paragraph *4* says(*emphasis mine*):

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. **If the first operand
>   compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated**.

Note, the second operand will not be evaluated *only if* the first is `false`. Also note it guarantees right to left evaluation and a sequence point after the first evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is true in function calls also.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    if(0&&printf("hello"))
    {
        printf("true");

    }
    else 
        printf("false");
}
```

for example consider the above code, it will give output as false. However replacing 0 by 1 in "if condition' will give output as "hellotrue."

Comment: Beware of printf's buffering. Either add `\n` to your messages or call `fflush(0);` when you need to ensure printing is done at this moment.

Comment: Also, any decent compiler would optimize away your condition (although that in itself stands as a proof)